# HERE Truck Transport Tile (trucknopttile)

Tags: here-api

We use Routing API v8 to build truck routes!
In our country constructed many new roads! But info on 'trucknopttile' tile is incorrect at now! Truck route  built in incorrect way!
How can we  improve this information and change this behavior?
Does v8 API have option like in v7  - 'truckRestrictionPenalty'?

Example:
[Wrong weights limit signs on the bridge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDSNF.png)

Example request:

```
routes?transportMode=truck&origin=49.81208246726337,24.157407830301196&destination=49.81755155059492,24.147335560752186&return=polyline,tolls,summary,routeHandle,passthrough,incidents&alternatives=3&currency=EUR&units=metric&departureTime=any&avoid%5Bfeatures%5D=seasonalClosure,uTurns&avoid%5BzoneCategories%5D=environmental&vehicle%5Btype%5D=tractor&vehicle%5Blength%5D=1650&vehicle%5Bwidth%5D=255&vehicle%5Bheight%5D=373&vehicle%5BgrossWeight%5D=38000&vehicle%5BweightPerAxle%5D=11500&vehicle%5BaxleCount%5D=5&vehicle%5BtrailerCount%5D=1&spans=incidents,length,duration,countryCode,routeNumbers,speedLimit,dynamicSpeedInfo,notices&apiKey={API KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

Routing v7 had a strict approach to truck restrictions. There, no route which violated some truck restriction(s) was ever returned. It was possible to change this behavior with truckRestrictionPenalty parameter, but even then Routing v7 provided only a generic notice: Code: routingOptionViolated, Text: truckRestriction.

If Routing v8 cannot find any route that obeys all specified options and vehicle parameters and that avoids all applicable restrictions, by default, the response will contain a route that violates some restrictions. The response will also contain a set of critical notices explaining which restrictions could not be avoided. In some areas, this is not possible, for example in Romania, where almost all of the main roads have a 11.5t per axle restriction.

For more detail please refer below api document.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/migration_guide/index.html